# pandas sum duplicated rows by column

Tags: python, pandas

i stuck with such problem: i have dataset:

```py
   Name   Year   patent_count   authors
3  Riti   2010        3            2
4  Riti   2010        3            3
5  Aadi   2012        2            1 
6  Aadi   2012        2            3
```

and i need to groupby this dataframe by Name, Year, patent_count and sum authors to get in conclusion Dataframe like this:

```py
   Name   Year   patent_count   authors
3  Riti   2010        3            5
6  Aadi   2012        2            4
```

i tried to do it usind pandas groupby.sum(), but it doesn't work

[this is real dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BNvp.jpg)
[this what i get after group by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhL3r.jpg)

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Name','Year','patent_count']).sum()`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: i add images of my real dataset

Comment: idk why, but variables authors, publications, forein publications, journal publications drops from dataframe instead of sum

Comment: try `df.groupby(['Name','Year','patent_count']).sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Please check new dupe.